# CNN model for binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

We are novice students in data science (and programming) and we are trying to build a cnn model for binary classification (male - female). Our accuracy is good enouch, 0.97, but the validation accuracy is 0.56 (we think there is overfitting). We have 4706 images - 70% for training and 30% for test/validation.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape=x_data_np.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

how can we improve the validation accuracy? Did we set correctly the model parameters? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be overfitting by a massive amount. Your dataset is quite small, and you are using way too many layers with no dropout nor batch normalization.

I suggest four ways to remedy this:

**1. Use a** `Dropout` **layer**

Dropout randomly switches off neurons with a certain probability (usual values are in the range 0.1-0.4). This is a great technique to reduce overfitting.

```
# The dropout probability should be tuned.
keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)
```

Dropout layers are usually added towards the top (i.e., later) layers in the network. The dropout probability itself is a hyperparameter that can be tuned.

**2. Perform data augmentation**

Data augmentation is a technique to artificially increase the amount of data. It performs transformations such as shifting, shearing, rotating and mirroring. Keras provides the `ImageDataGenerator` class to handle this very easily.

Organize your data into train, validation and test directories. Each of the directories must contain subdirectories for the two classes - male and female.

The directory tree will look as follows (say you are doing a binary classification of males and females):

```
.
├── test
│   ├── male
│   └── female
├── train
│   ├── male
│   └── female
└── validation
    ├── male
    └── female
```

Then initialize data generators for training and testing, rescale the images from 0-255 to 0-1 range if you desire.

```
# Performing data augmentation only on the training set.
train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255
    # Performing data augmentation
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=10,
    horizontal_flip=True, # Horizontally flipped version is still an image of a person.
)
# Data generator for validation and testing.
test_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

Then read the training, validation and test images as batches from the `flow_from_directory` method.

```
train = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train', target_size=(128, 128), batch_size=32)
validation = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/validation', target_size=(128, 128), batch_size=32)
test = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/test', target_size=(128, 128), batch_size=32)
```

Once you've executed the above code, make sure it tells you it's found the correct number of images with the correct number of classes.

You can then pass `train`, `validation` and `test` batches directly to the `fit` method in your keras model. **Make sure you specify the number of** `steps_per_epoch` **and** `validation_steps` **while training.** This is because generators run forever, continuously generating images, so `fit` needs to know when to stop. Make sure you provide the `steps` argument to the `predict` method as well, for the same reason.

Refer:
[Keras docs](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)

**3. Use early stopping**

Make a callback to stop when validation accuracy starts increasing. Also make learning curves (plots of training and validation loss vs epoch) to check where your model starts to overfit.

```
callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping()
```

You can pass parameters to the callback. Check the documentation.

Refer: [Keras docs](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/)

Pass this callback to the `fit` method of your model in a list with your other callbacks.

**4. Use batch normalization**

Adding a batch normalization layer helps reduce overfitting too.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by adding **BatchNormalization** layer after each but last **Activation** layer. This will enhance regularization and hopefully, boost validation accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your model suffers from overfitting. Consider adding regularization to your model. Try adding Dropout layer after your Dense(64) layer or add l2 regularization to your Dense layers. If that doesn't help try data augmentation if you haven't done that.

At this point, you probably should iteratively improve your model by tweaking hyperparameters (number of neurons in the last layers, number of layers, kernel sizes, number of kernels etc.)